# Margin setting not consistent

Tags: margins

I'm currently typing my dissertation. The requirement for text margin is top 2cm, right 2cm, left 4cm and bottom 2cm. My setting works for all pages, except the pages at which the chapter titles are located. Is there anyway to solve it? I'm using pdfLaTeX compiler.

```
**\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{faktor} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%for page number font
\usepackage{lmodern}%also for page number font
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, calc, cleveref}
\usepackage{mathptmx}%Font: Times New Roman
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font={small},labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[notquote]{hanging}
\usepackage{sectsty}.
  \chapternumberfont{\nohang\centering\large\MakeUppercase} 
  \chaptertitlefont{\nohang\centering\large\MakeUppercase}
  \sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\geometry{
   left=40mm,
   right=20mm,
   top=20mm,
   bottom=20mm,
 }
 %%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{CHAPTER } 
   \cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{6em}      

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 %%%%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
%%%%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%%%%%

\setstretch{2}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
%Chapter 1
\chapter{\MakeUppercase{INTRODUCTION}}

\section{Background of study} 
Associating a group with a graph and finding relationships between them is 
an area of research that has generated much interest. Research on this 
subject aims at investigating relationships between groups and graphs and at 
exploring applications of one to the other.
\newpage
The main contributions of this work
\end{document}**
```

Comment: This is because the chapter title has inserts blank space above it. You have to change the format of the `\chapter{}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I eliminated the blank space. However, it doesn't work. Is there any other way to solve it?